# Am I pricing this equivalent of Efficient Quiver correctly?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, crafting, pricing

So, I'm going to be playing a Wizard in a friend's pathfinder game soon. I wanted to make a custom magic item, similar to the Efficient Quiver. At the time I had only skimmed the Efficient Quivers abilities and assumed it only worked with arrows and bows. So I looked to the custom magic item creation rules to determine the DC and gold price to make what is essentially a golf bag for my Metamagic Rods that carries a lot of them.

My assumption based on reading the rules; the DC is 5 + the Caster Level for the item (Which I assume is my character's Caster Level, in this case 12) and thus the DC for this would be 17. Now we move on to the cost, as determined by the formulae found on the "Table: Estimating Magic Item Gold Piece Values" as this new magic item is based on the Efficient Quiver, using the same spell (Secret Chest: Wizard/Sorc 5), and using the crafter's caster level (12), as the effect I want is a continuous effect the cost formula is as follows: (Spell level × caster level × 2,000 gp squared)

Now I did the math, and If I'm following PEMDAS correctly then my math process goes as follows

**5 (Spell level) x 12 (Caster Level) = 60**

**60 x 2000gp = 120,000**

**120,000<sup>2</sup> = 14 400 000 000gp**

This item, which is near identical to the Efficient Quiver is 8 millions times the price of the item in question.

Am I doing the math wrong? Is the formula an error that got FAQ'd or Errata'd? Because then this object would be impossible to craft.

Comment: Hi Mouse! Welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information. Do you have a link or reference to where you are getting this formula from? We can't tell you if it is a typo or a mistake if we don't know where you are reading it from. Thanks for contributing and happy gaming!

Comment: Why did you need a specific item for this - why not just use a Handy Haversack?

Comment: @YogoZuno OP Points out that they realized they could just use the Efficient Quiver and this was more of a "what should this actually cost" than asking about a rod-holding solution

Comment: Heads up, you get to pick the Caster Level of items you create; the default is the minimum Caster Level of the highest level spell used in the crafting. So for Efficient Quiver, which is based on a [5th level Wizard spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/secret-chest), the CL is 9. You can choose to adjust the CL up for the purpose of spell effect damage and difficulty to disable with Dispel and similar effects.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking at [this](http://legacy.aonprd.com/coreRulebook/magicItems/magicItemCreation.html)?

> Use-activated or continuous | Spell level × caster level × 2,000 gp<sup>2</sup>

**The <sup>2</sup> is a reference to footnote 2 - not a mathematical squared notation.** (Of course, if it *did* mean squared [which it doesn't] then order of operations means you only square the 2,000).

> <sup>2</sup> If a continuous item has an effect based on a spell with a duration measured in rounds, multiply the cost by 4. If the duration of the spell is 1 minute/level, multiply the cost by 2, and if the duration is 10 minutes/level, multiply the cost by 1.5. If the spell has a 24-hour duration or greater, divide the cost in half.

So the spell level is 5, the caster level is 9 (because you would create this at the lowest level needed to cast 5th level spells) giving \$5 \times 9 \times 2,000 = 90,000\$gp and, because the spells' duration is greater than 24 hours, you divide this in half giving \$45,000\$gp. The DC is 14.

Comment: The querent is *also* wrong on a separate count; namely that line refers to items that replicate a spell effect, not merely items similar to an item that has such a spell as a prerequisite!  Many cheap low-level trinkets have high-level spells as a prerequisite and pricing them as a contunital item of said high-level spells would be crazy-- surely a *Meridian Belt* ought not cost the same as an at-will *polymorph* belt.  Furthermore, if one were to do so, one ought also to include the cost of the focus component for said spells (the OP did not).